# Vertical lines appear in my screen on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, firefox, google-chrome, display, intel-graphics

Vertical lines started appearing in my screen on 12.04 all of a sudden. 
Dell Inspiron 6GB machine. This behavior is seen on the latest versions of Chrome/FireFox browsers.What should I do to resolve this issue.

Refer: http://pasteboard.co/22LsUxiM.png

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"

lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05e9
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Refer:

driver details - obtained using mesa-utils

[image]

machine info

[image]

```
uname -a; dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core
Linux seoul 3.13.0-35-generic #62~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 18 14:52:04 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
rc  xserver-xorg-core                                                    2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8                                                    Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-core-lts-quantal                                        2:1.13.0-0ubuntu6.5~precise1                                            Xorg X server - core server

sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)




acpi -V Battery 0: Discharging, 15%, 00:21:53 remaining Battery 0: design capacity 2800 mAh, last full capacity 1743 mAh = 62% Adapter 0: off-line Cooling 0: pkg-temp-0 no state information available Cooling 1: LCD 0 of 99 Cooling 2: intel_powerclamp no state information available Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 10 Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 10 Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10 Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 10
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Do I need to install anything from here - https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/13815/Intel-Graphics-Drivers-for-Linux-

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `uname -a; dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core` terminal command.

Comment: Post a photo of the problem on your screen

Comment: @solsTiCe I added few pictures of the problem from this page itself in the ticket body

Comment: @Rpj: In the future, please use the image icon at the top of the editor box to upload images.

Comment: So what ? what is the problem ? vertical bar in blue menu are a feature of the linuxg.net site... I said photo not screenshot

Comment: The vertical bars which are seen, actually flicker forming a band. I will try and get a photo.

Comment: Added couple of photos which show the problem, appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Appreciate inputs on resolving this issue, also all Dell screen tests on start passed OK

Comment: Appreciate inputs on resolving this issue, the filcker has worsened.

Comment: This issue is still unresolved, can someone help..

Comment: This issue is still unresolved, can someone help..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest upgrading your graphical stack.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty:i386
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty
```

This will upgrade Intel driver too and your system should be 12.04.5.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't make a difference. I can try to re-boot the system shortly. I already made an upgrade to 12.04.5

Comment: You can test it after reboot, not before. And your stack is not from 12.04.5.

Comment: Just rebooted.. at /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"

Comment: sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.

Comment: And how is your screen?

Comment: I see the same problem again, it usually takes a while to appear in my screen. I see it right on this ticket page at the top.

Comment: This looks like a hardware fail or overheating, if it appears after a while. Maybe your cooling fan is broken.

Comment: Please do not post additional information to comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: How do I find more info on the cooling fan status?

Comment: Your temps look OK. Can you take a PHOTO of your screen? I do not see any lines on a screenshot.

Comment: I have attached a picture, hope you can view the problem

Comment: @Rpj I do not see any artifacts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26083/discussion-between-rpj-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 0):

You should use following drivers [Intel Graphics for Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2015q2-intel-graphics-stack-release). Here is GUI Friendly installer: [Intel Graphics Installer for Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.1.0). I see that you use version 12.04, seems it's not supperted already.

I know, that proposition upgrade your current installation to new version is not solution, but I will suggest you.

Meantime, please report this issue here: [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel)